# OPENAI API Completion not returning text

Tags: node.js, openai-api

I am using node.js and want to use openai API

I just copied the code from openai playground and it looks like this

```
export const askOpenAi = async () => {
const response = await openai.createCompletion("text-davinci-001", {
    prompt: "\ninput: What is human life expectancy in the United States?\n",
    temperature: 0,
    max_tokens: 100,
    top_p: 1,
    frequency_penalty: 0,
    presence_penalty: 0,
    stop: ["\n", "\ninput:"],
});
return response.data;
}
```

openai's Returning data look like this

```
{
  id: '~~~',
  object: 'text_completion',
  created: ~~~,
  model: 'text-davinci:001',
  choices: [ { text: '', index: 0, logprobs: null, finish_reason: 'stop' } ]
}
```

In the playground, this code works very well.

[image: In the playground, this code works very well.]

How can I get right response?

Comment: Oh.. I just fixed it

Change prompt into -> prompt: `\n\nQ: ${question}\nA:`,

Answer (score 9):

It should be something like this:

```
export const askOpenAi = async () => {
const prompt = `input: What is human life expectancy in the United States?
output:`
const response = await openai.createCompletion("text-davinci-001", {
    prompt: prompt,
    temperature: 0,
    max_tokens: 100,
    top_p: 1,
    frequency_penalty: 0,
    presence_penalty: 0,
    stop: ["input:"],
});
return response.data;
}
```

Here, first of all, remove the \n from stop array, because then it will stop the completion after every newline (any answer could be in multiple lines). secondly, no need to add extra \n before input:. it doesnt matter actually.

Finally, remember to give some clue about the completion you're expecting by adding output: at the last of your prompt.

Btw, these type of question ask completion can be achieved through openAI's new instruct mode as well.

```
const prompt = `Answer the following question:
What is human life expectancy in the United States?
{}`
const response = await openai.createCompletion("text-davinci-001", {
    prompt: prompt,
    temperature: .7,
    max_tokens: 100,
    top_p: 1,
    frequency_penalty: 0,
    presence_penalty: 0,
    stop: ["{}"],
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change
`stop: ["\n"]` in something different. Worked in my case!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. What solved it for me, was to add a whitespace (not a `\n` or `{}`) at the end of the prompt, and omit the `stop` key entirely from the request params.